# How can I include two Model Class Tracks and Artists in one FirestoreRecyclerAdapter in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

My android project has **two models** - *Track and Artist*.

Track is used to get the information related to Track and Artist is used to get the details related to Artist.

Here is the sample code for the each model:
**Track.class**

```
public class Track {
    private int track_ID;
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String songWriter;
    private String lyrics;
    private String album;
    private String language;
    private int views;
    private int year;
    private String albumArt;
    private String videoURL;
    private String shareURL;

    public Track(){
        //Empty Constructor
    }
```

**Artist.class**

```
private int artist_ID;
    private String name;
    private boolean verified;
    private String artistProfilePic;

    public Artist(){
        //Empty Constructor
    }
```

In the code below *I am only able to use Track Model*

```
public class SongAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Track, SongAdapter.SongHolder> {
```

My problem is I am not able to use both the model in one FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you change your models? Why don't you have a relationship between Track and Artist instead having Artist properties duplicated in Track?

Comment: @Maria Sorry, my mistake, I updated my Code. Also Track and Artist are different collections in firestore. So now how I Can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapters in FirebaseUI can only show homogeneous results from a single collection.

If you want to show results from multiple collections, or show heterogenous results from a single collection, you will have to build your own adapter. This is not as complex as some folks think. Give it a try, and post back if you get stuck.

I recommend having a look at the [`FirestoreArray` class from FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreArray.java) if you want to see how it loads the data from the database and keeps it in memory.